# property was already registered by 'FrameworkElement'

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, frameworks, element

I am writing two dependency properties and I keep getting the "[Property] was already registered by 'FrameworkElement'" error in the design window of VS11.  Here is a snippet of my code

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditingNumbers", typeof(bool), typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

the problem seems to be the 3rd parameter (owner parameter typeof(FrameworkElement)).  If I set the 3rd parameter to the class the contains two dependency properties, the error goes away, but I cannot use the properties directly from xaml.  I would have to add ownership for each dependency property before I use it.

Actually, It does render correctly, but only when I first open it.  Immediately after the first render it will give me an exception.  At runtime, it seems to work perfectly.

Am I doing something wrong and is there a way to get rid of this annoying error?

---- Edit -----

Here is my custom class (includes 2 of the Dependency Properties):

```
public partial class EditableTextBox : UserControl
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditingNumber", typeof(bool), typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("0", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) 
        { 
            CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback((sender,value) =>
                {
                    return expressionRestaraint.Match((string)value).Value;
                })
        });
    #endregion

    public static Regex expressionRestaraint = new Regex("[-a-zA-z0-9+*.\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]*");

    public string Text
    {
        get { (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            tbxValue.Text = (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
    }

    public bool IsEditingNumber
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty); 
        }
        set 
        {
            bool old = (bool)GetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty);
            if (old != value)
            {
                if (!value)
                    stopEditing();
                else
                    startEditing();

                SetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty, value);
            }
        }
    } . . .
```

Use in Main Class:

```
<Window x:Class="VisualMathExpression.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:edit="clr-namespace:VisualMathExpression.EditableTextBox"
    xmlns:all="clr-namespace:VisualMathExpression"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <edit:EditableTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Text="af" IsEditingNumber="True" /> . . .
```

--- Edit ---
Wrapper fixed (problem that cause xaml property not to change when ownership belonged to the declared class)

```
    public partial class EditableTextBox : UserControl
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditingNumber", typeof(bool), typeof(EditableTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) 
        { 
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback((sender, arg) =>
                {
                    EditableTextBox ed = sender as EditableTextBox;
                    if (!(bool)arg.NewValue)
                        ed.stopEditing();
                    else
                        ed.startEditing();
                }),
        });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(EditableTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("0", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) 
        { 
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback((sender,arg) =>
                {
                    EditableTextBox ed = sender as EditableTextBox;
                    ed.tbxValue.Text = arg.NewValue as string;
                }),
            CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback((sender,value) =>
                {
                    return expressionRestaraint.Match((string)value).Value;
                })
        });
    #endregion

    public static Regex expressionRestaraint = new Regex("[-a-zA-z0-9+*.\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]*");

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsEditingNumber
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: The Number/Numbers discrepancy is against guidelines but probably not the cause.

Comment: I actually changed that in purpose to see if it was conflicting with the wrapper . . . the issue went away for one build and then the problem came back again.

Comment: Just saw you unaccepted the answer. For a specific reason?

Answer (score 59):

The third parameter `ownerType` of the [DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) method must be the class that declares the property.

If your class is `MyClass` the declaration would have to look like this:

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsEditingNumber", typeof(bool), typeof(MyClass), ...);

    // CLR wrapper
    public bool IsEditingNumber
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditingNumberProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then if I use MyClass inside say Main, the xaml attribute doesnt work unless I add the ownership by MyClass.IsEditingNumberProperty.AddOwner(Main) inside a static constructor.  I'd have to do this for each of the Dependency Property.  Is there another way?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "xaml attribute doesnt work". Did you perhaps simply forget to add the CLR wrapper for your dependency property? Also the class that declares the property must be derived from DependencyObject (or a derived class), unless it is an attached property. See the edited answer.

Comment: you dont seem very convinced . . . allow me to post more of my code (perhaps i should've done this from the start, sorry). the problem is i can't use my dependency properties from XAML.

Comment: You should *never* do anything else except GetValue/SetValue in the CLR wrappers. They won't get called when using the property in XAML. Use a PropertyChangedCallback (via metadata) instead. See the *Implementing the Wrapper* section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist).

Comment: And still you use `typeof(FrameworkElement)` as owner type. That's wrong. You must use `typeof(EditableTextBox)`.

Comment: I can't access my Textbox objects from PropertyChangedCallback or CoerceCallback.

Comment: You can. The first parameter is a reference to your EditableTextBox instance. Just cast from DependencyObject to EditableTextBox. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.aspx).

Comment: Oh yes. the wrapper, it caused all the problems.  thank you.  i will update my code just in case you are curious . . .

Comment: And don't forget to fix the owner type.